# How to plot_tree for pipelined MultiOutput Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I want to interpret my model, to learn why this model gives me 1 or 0 for labels.
, so i want to use plot_tree function from xgboost.
My problem is a multi label classification problem;
I wrote following code;

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

model = MultiOutputClassifier(
        xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",
                         colsample_bytree = 0.5,
                          gamma = 0.1
                         ))

#Define a pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([("preprocessing", col_transformers), ("XGB", model)])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = pipeline.predict(X_test)

xgb.plot_tree(pipeline, num_trees=4)
```

This code gives me the error;

> 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'get_dump'

If i change the code ;

```
xgb.plot_tree(pipeline.named_steps["XGB"], num_trees=4)
```

> 'MultiOutputClassifier' object has no attribute 'get_dump'

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the `plot_tree` function on `Booster` or `XGBModel` instances. Your first case fails as you are passing a `Pipeline` object, and in the second case you are passing the `MultiOutputClassifier` object.

Instead, you have to pass the fitted `XGBClassifier` objects. However, be aware of how [`MultiOutputClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn-multioutput-multioutputclassifier) actually works:

> This strategy consists of fitting one classifier per target.

This means you will have **one fitted model for each label**.

You can access them with the `estimators_` attribute of `MultiOutputClassifier`. For example, you can retrieve the model for the first label like this:

```py
xgb.plot_tree(pipeline.named_steps["XGB"].estimators_[0], num_trees=4)
```

If want all, you would have to loop over the list returned by the `estimators_` attribute.